# Django model structure for question with type and subtype

Tags: python, django, database, foreign-keys

is this type of model schema okay
i have a question which will for sure have a type but the subtype is optional

```
class QuestionType(models.Model):
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_type

class QuestionSubType(models.Model):
    question_type = models.ForeignKey(QuestionType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_sub_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Question(QuestionAbstractModel):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.ForeignKey(QuestionType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    type_subtype = models.ForeignKey(QuestionSubType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    solution_url = models.URLField(max_length=555, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.chapter.subject.grade} {self.chapter.subject.name} {self.chapter.name} {self.type}"
```

is this model schema okay or can i improve it in any way

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions to improve your models:

1. It's better not to use type field in Question model, you can access
   the type of question from subtype field. Look at Question type as
   grouping for subtypes.
2. You have used optional fields in the **str** method of your Question
   model class that can be null, you should check this in **str**,
   otherwise, you will come up with an error.
3. You cannot call the FK field like this in **str** method
   f"{self.type}". You should rewrite the **str** method of
   QuestionSubType
   model and call str(self.type_subtype).

   ```
   class Question(QuestionAbstractModel):
       chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       type_subtype = models.ForeignKey(QuestionSubType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
       solution_url = models.URLField(max_length=555, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       chapter_str = f"{self.chapter.subject.grade} {self.chapter.subject.name} {self.chapter.name}" if self.chapter else "No Chapter"
       type_subtype_str = str(self.type_subtype) if self.type_subtype else "No Type/Subtype"
       return f"{chapter_str} {type_subtype_str}"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

1. If a question's subtype is supposed to be directly related to its type, you should enforce this relationship integrity at the model level.
2. If you frequently access a question's type and subtype together, consider using Django's select_related in your queries to prefetch related objects and reduce the number of database hits.